# How Can I Get googleMap Object in angular agm Library to work with google HeatMap?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, heatmap

I want to get googleMap object in agm and use to create HeatMapLayer in my project but this code not working:

```
declare var google: any;

@Directive({
  selector: 'my-comp',
})
export class MyComp {
  constructor(private _gmap:GoogleMapsAPIWrapper){
    _gmap.getMap().then((m: mapTypes.GoogleMap) => {
      console.log(google);
    });
  }
}
```

I read GitHub repo issues and everyone says this code is working but for me, it does not work. why?

Comment: try  ```this._gmap.getMap().then((m: mapTypes.GoogleMap) => {
      console.log(m);
    });```

Comment: @fatemefazli That's not working.

Comment: Can you give more details on what exactly is not working?

Comment: any code inside 
`.then((m: mapTypes.GoogleMap) => {
      // my cods
    })` not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my answer in in a chat room and i like to share with you

```
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
declare var google: any;

@Component({

  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: // your url,

})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( public mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader ) {}

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then((x) => {
          this.map = new google.maps.Map( this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
            zoom: 13,
            center: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          }

          /* do anything you want with google map object */
      });
    }
}
```

i hope you like.